# For XSS protection, do I need to escape before populating for edit

Tags: php, security, forms, xss

I have an infected text that I'm testing with.

In display mode, I get the data from the database and display it on the page, and I get the XSS as expected.

In edit mode, I use the same form I used for initial entry and I populate the value from the database into the input fields (textarea in this case), but I'm not getting the XSS. Is this normal? Are form fields data not susceptible to XSS because the text is being displayed inside the form field? so no need for the XSS protection I use in normal display?

By the way, the specific XSS I'm testing with is this. I got it from the cheat sheet for XSS on [hackers](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html), the fisrt one.

```
';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//\";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//--></SCRIPT>">'><SCRIPT>alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Just be conscious of the output encoding too - some editors may put untrusted data into JavaScript which requires a different escaping syntax to HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the form fields **are** suspectible for XSS, so you need to escape them  as well

Template sample:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="{$value}" />
```

Value sample:

```
" /><script>alert(123);</script><input attr="
```

Result:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="" /><script>alert(42);</script><input attr="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

An example.

```
</TEXTAREA><SCRIPT>alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))</SCRIPT>
```